# Apache reverse proxy to gitlab hosted on another server

Tags: apache, proxy, gitlab, reverse-proxy

I'm trying for the past months to use Apache as a reverse proxy but I can't manage to configure it the way I want.

***Network configuration***

In my local network, all incoming HTTP requests are routed by my firewall to an Apache server (running on **Debian**). This Apache server hosts 3 different Web services.

A fourth web service, **Gitlab**, is hosted on a second server (**Ubuntu**) and runs in a docker. Gitlab is referenced by my internal DNS as `gitlab/`. So, I can access it in my browser from the URL `http://gitlab/`.

***Desired Apache behavior***

I would like to access to these 4 different web services from the Internet by typing in my browser :

```
http://ip_address/web_service_1/
http://ip_address/web_service_2/
http://ip_address/web_service_3/
http://ip_address/gitlab/
```

Web_service_1 to web_service_3 work perfectly. But I can't figure how to configure Apache as a proxy to Gitlab.

From the Internet, a request to Gitlab should go through the firewall, be routed to the **Debian** server running Apache and finally to the **Ubuntu** server running Gitlab.

Unfortunately, when I send a request to `http://ip_address/gitlab`, I receive `http://ip_address/users/sign_in` instead of `http://ip_address/gitlab/users/sign_in` and Apache cannot route next requests to Gitlab be cause the `/gitlab/` part disappeared.

***Apache configuration***

To get the results explained above, I've created a file named `/etc/apache2/sites-available/proxy.conf` on the Debian server which contains :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myProxy
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^/web_service_1(.*) http://debian_server/web_service_1/$1
   RewriteRule ^/web_service_2(.*) http://debian_server/web_service_2/$1
   RewriteRule ^/web_service_3(.*) http://debian_server/web_service_3/$1
   ProxyPass /gitlab http://gitlab/
   ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://gitlab/
</VirtualHost>
```

As you know, this doesn't work as expected : the `/gitlab/` part disappears from the URL.

After a lot of researches and tests, I found a tutorial which brought me a better result ... not working either. My `proxy.conf` is now :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName myProxy 
    ServerAlias myProxy
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    RewriteEngine On
    LogLevel error trace6
    RewriteRule ^/web_service_1(.*) http://127.0.2.1/web_service_1/$1 [P]
    RewriteRule ^/web_service_2(.*) http://127.0.2.2/web_service_2/$1 [P]   
    RewriteRule ^/web_service_3(.*) http://127.0.2.3/web_service_3/$1 [P]   
    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPass /gitlab/ http://gitlab/

    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://gitlab /gitlab

    <Location /gitlab/>
        ProxyPassReverse /
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /gitlab/
        RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this solution, I almost get the sign in page, but some elements are missing and I can't log in. Maybe I forgot some option in the proxy configuration ...

Does anyone know how to improve this solution and make it works ?

Thanks a lot for your help.